# How can I figure out a set of values that most of my population will hit 99% of the time?

Tags: standard-deviation

I am not a math person, I'm trying to put together a spreadsheet in excel that takes the square footage for every property in a county as the only input.

I want to then generate a list of square footage range amounts that in plain english represents;

> with almost >90% ( or something) accuracy every property you have will
>   fall in one of these ranges.

So instead of having 900,000 records, I have x number of "ranges"...that almost everyone would fall into....

I'm thinking this will involve stddev and what not but I am clueless.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of all the square footages in a spreadsheet. Why not just sort these values and then pick $x$ ranges that contain 99% of the values?

Comment: I'm not a math person what is that symbol?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a [prediction interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval). If you assume a normal distribution you will need to estimate the parameters and then apply the formula: $\overline{X}_n\pm T_a {s}_n\sqrt{1+(1/n)}$ (for a two sided interval)

If you are not a math person, perhaps it would be safer to something premade for excel. A google search for "prediction interval excel" gave some promising results with free software. It would also be more flexible to use, if you wish to modify the $T_a$, which is typically [found in a table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Table_of_selected_values).

Comment: I found this link.  http://mtsu32.mtsu.edu:11308/regression/level2/predint/using_formula.htm  The bottom line of their results are sort of what I want.   I'll update my question.

Comment: I know what you want, and my answer is just that. You will need to compute $\overline{X}_n$ and $s_n$ for your data (see wikipedia page) and then take $T_a$ from the table in the link.